# Create a link - Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, data-binding

I have a default.js which stores my data like this:

```
 {
                     id: 2
                    , title: 'testitem'
                    , url: 'http://www.alink.com/item=112920'
                    , dependsOn: [1]


            },
```

I want in my default.html a link which is created from the url above.

I tried it like this:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: url }">
Testitem
</a>
```

But nothing appears. If I try something with the "title" attribute it works:

```
   <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your **data object** in a **variable** and you have to **activate** the knockout.js binding.

```
var data = {
    id: 2,
    title: "Hello world",
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    dependsOn: [1]
};

 // Activates knockout.js
 ko.applyBindings(data);
```

and your **HTML**

```
<h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
<a data-bind="attr: { href: url }">
Testitem
</a>
```

then everything will work fine. You just have to ***activate*** your **knockout.js** binding.

You can find the code here.
https://codepen.io/AElkhodary/pen/ZrxrqV

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see normally it should working. I can´t get it to work for seomehow. This is the default.js: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpLZYx  . I´ve activated the knockout.js at the end. In the html view the title output works fine, but the link can´t be created

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpLZYx  Here is the html code. I´ve entered the data-bind attribute in line 65+